# JDBC Connection interface object

Tags: jdbc

In java.sql package we have Connection interface to establish connection with database.

And with the help of DirverManager class we can get the object of Connection interface.
Ex.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DNS");
```

But I have some confusion ---
      if Connection is an interface then how can we get the object of Connection interface?

Please clear this confusion.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot create any object for any interface. But it is possible to assign a class object which is implementing that interface to the reference variable of that interface. Here *con* is a reference variable to that interface, and *DriverManager.getConnection()* returns a class object which implements the *Connection* interface.

Comment: But i want to know DirverManager.getConnection()  returns which class object.(means which class implements the Connection interface) .

Comment: Now which class implements _Connection_ is driver specific. The JDBC driver which you use has a .jar file associated with it, and the classes defined in it implements these interfaces. Each of these statements returns an object. You see nothing is initialized the normal class-object way using _new object()_.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's `T4CConnection` class implements the `Connection` interface and Mysql's `JDBC4Connection` class also implements the `Connection` interface.

This means your `con` reference variable in the line below holds either a `T4CConnection` class obj if you load Oracle Driver or a `JDBC4Connection` class obj if you load mysql driver.

`Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DNS");`

Answer (score 0):

In J2EE, we code with Interfaces rather than classes as from vendor to vendor and driver to driver the class name change. To get the implementation class name use getClass().